# Why is event.preventDefault() in dragstart interrupting furthur drag events from executing?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to drag over an image and in order to stop the browser's default image drag, I am using event.preventDefault(). But for some reason it is interrupting further events like dragenter, dragover, dragend etc from executing. Why is this and How can I stop browser's default function without interrupting normal drag events.

```
<img src="/img/image1" id="img1"/>
```

jQuery

```
var obj=$('#ironman');  
obj.on('dragstart', function (e) {
      //e.preventDefault();
      console.log("dragstart");
  });

  obj.on('dragenter', function (e) {
      console.log("dragenter");
  });

  obj.on('dragover', function () {
      console.log("dragover");
  });
  obj.on('dragleave', function () {
      console.log("dragleave");
  });

  obj.on('dragend', function () {
      console.log("dragend");
  });
```

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e6P8b/)

Comment: Why are you trying to prevent it then? The default action of dragstart *is* dragging. What "default function" do you want to stop?

Comment: @Bergi, I am looking to create annotations over the image. So the browser's default behavior is standing in the way. I do know a workaround (using image as a background) but I do not want to use that.

Comment: What do you need dragging for when creating image annotations? Can't you use the classical mousedown/move/up events?

Comment: Yes I realized my mistake. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is a tough one as you are stopping native drag chain event on the element. Not sure why you want to do this, but one way to implement the native dragging is to cancel it and deal with mouse events

```
var obj=$('#ironman');  
obj.on('mousedown', function (e) {
  console.log("mousedown");
  // bind to the mousemove event
  obj.on('mousemove', function (e) {
      console.log("mousemove");
  });
});

obj.on('mouseup', function (e) {
  console.log("mouseup");
  // unbind the mousemove event
  obj.unbind('mousemove');
});
obj.on('dragstart', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();  // cancel the native drag event chain
  console.log("dragstart");
});
```

Comment: Thanks,  I am looking to create annotations over the image. So the browser's default behavior is standing in the way. I do know a workaround (using image as a background) but I do not want to use that.