# Mouse and Touch Events

Tags: jquery, events, touch, mouse, gallery

I am building a totally custom photo gallery and am currently working on the fullscreen view of an album.

Now I have built it so that you can use touchevents to slide the images left and right and to being in the next and previous ones. It works really nicely, however I also want this to work on desktop machines without touchscreens there I need to cater for mousevents too.

I found this small library: https://github.com/Tundra-Interactive/swipe.jquery.js and have integrated that but when I start dragging with the mouse over my photo, the built in chrome feature is activated and the picture jumps out so I can drag it to another application/my desktop in order to save/download a copy for myself. It slightly fades  the image out whilst dragging too.

How can I disable this so I can concentrate on the mouse events?

and also are there better ways of adapting my touch events to work on desktops as I explained?

Answer (score 0):

This might help you [Why is event.preventDefault() in dragstart interrupting furthur drag events from executing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19036977/why-is-event-preventdefault-in-dragstart-interrupting-furthur-drag-events-from)

You just prevent the default drag behaviour of the browser and then handle the dragging yourself with mouse down and mouseup events.